# call() is never called

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am learning how to use Observable.create(). so i created the below posted example. but when I run the App. and click the button the log statement in the 
call() method is never displayed while the log statement inside .create() gets displayed immediately.
I expected the log statement inside call() to be displayed, but it did not.

please let me know how why the following log statement
                    Log.i(TAG, "++++++++++ STARTED +++++++++");

never displayed.

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnStart = null;
private TextView tvText = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    this.tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);

     Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            Log.i(TAG, "++++++++++ STARTED +++++++++");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return null;
        }
    })
            .create(e -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "++++++++++ CREATED +++++++++");
                btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        e.onNext(i[0]++);
                    }
                });
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Object o) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "o: " + o.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: `create` is a static method, invoking it on an instance `Observable` has no effect and you practically throw away `Observable.fromCreate`. Please go through the official [Getting started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

The observable you create from the callable is essentially discarded when you call create which creates a new stream that you actually subscribe to.

- You can image you create one stream
- Then you create another stream
- But your subscription only applies to the second